# Indexed Stacking in Flutter. How to display container above all other widgets?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I try to create a notification button which shows all unread notifications inside the app how we know it from social media apps.

When clicking the notification icon I want to open the list with all new notifications.

My problem: I can't get stacking to work. I'm working with `Stack` widget but I need the list container float above all other widgets. It always has to be on top.

**How its look like**

[image]

As you can see the blue container is not in front of all widgets. How can we manage it in Flutter to bring it in front of all? Something like `position: fixed; z-index: 9999` in CSS.

**My code**

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Get.theme.colorScheme.primary.darken(.05),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
        child: WindowTitleBarBox(
          child: MoveWindow(
            child: NotificationBar(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            MainNavigation(),
            Flexible(child: this.child!),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);


class NotificationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NotificationBar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, right: 35),
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Indexer(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.notifications,
            size: 25,
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 12,
            bottom: 12,
            child: Badge(
              content: "2",
              minHeight: 5,
              minWidth: 12,
              fontSize: 7,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              width: 300,
              height: 500,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Overlay`:

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Overlay Test'),
  onPressed: () {
    final entry = OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        bottom: 20,
        right: 20,
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
    );
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(entry);
  },
)
```

To remove it, call `entry.remove()`. You might want to store the `entry` variable higher for easier access, maybe as a class member variable.